# Where does Django store auth's superuser / pw / e-mail data?

Tags: django, django-authentication

After running syncdb and creating a su, where does that get recorded?  Settings.py doesn't seem to change.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It gets recorded as an instance of [`django.contrib.auth.models.User`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#users).

Comment: Which is to say that its stored in the database in a table called auth_user.

Comment: To add to that, you can find information about which table is being used by looking at the `DATABASES` section of the `settings.py` file or whatever `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` is pointing to.